# trouble with solving knapsack issue via dynamic programming in C

Tags: c, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I need to solve the knapsack problem recursively, memoized and with dynamic programming. Currently I'm stuck at the dynamic programming method.

I adapted the code from what I found elsewhere on the internet. Currently the output is not correct.

The problem involves profit and mass. Each item has a profit and mass associated, there is a MAX_N (umber) of items available and a MAX_CAPACITY for mass. The aim is to have as much "profit" in the knapsack as possible.

Here is an example provided by the exercise:

> Example: Given a knapsack of capacity 5, and items with mass[] = {2, 4, 3, 2}
>   and profit profit[] = {45, 40, 25, 15}, the best combination would be item 0 (with mass 2 and profit 45) and item 2 (with mass 3 and with profit 25) for a total profit of 70. No other combination with mass 5 or less has a greater profit.

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_N 10
#define MAX_CAPACITY 165

int m[MAX_N][MAX_CAPACITY];

int max(int x, int y) {
    return x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));
}

int min(int x, int y) {
    return y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y));
}

int knapsackRecursive(int capacity, int mass[], int profit[], int n) {

    if (n < 0)
        return 0;

    if (mass[n] > capacity)
        return knapsackRecursive(capacity, mass, profit, n-1);

    else
        return max(knapsackRecursive(capacity, mass, profit, n-1), knapsackRecursive(capacity - mass[n], mass, profit, n-1) + profit[n]);

}

int knapsackMemoized(int capacity, int mass[], int profit[], int n) {

}

int knapsackDynamic(int capacity, int mass[], int profit[], int n) {

    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j <= capacity; j++) {

            if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                m[i][j] = 0;

            else if (mass[i-1] <= j)
                m[i][j] = max(profit[i-1] + m[i-1][j-mass[i-1]], m[i-1][j]);

            else
                m[i][j] = m[i-1][j];
        }
    }

    return m[n][capacity];

}

void test() {

    // test values
    //int M1[MAX_N] = {2, 4, 3, 2};
    //int P1[MAX_N] = {45, 40, 25, 10};

    int M1[MAX_N] = {6, 3, 2, 4};
    int P1[MAX_N] = {50, 60, 40, 20};

    int M2[MAX_N] = {23, 31, 29, 44, 53, 38, 63, 85, 89, 82};
    int P2[MAX_N] = {92, 57, 49, 68, 60, 43, 67, 84, 87, 72};

    // a)
    printf("Recursion: %d\n",knapsackRecursive(MAX_CAPACITY, M1, P1, MAX_N));
    printf("Recursion: %d\n",knapsackRecursive(MAX_CAPACITY, M2, P2, MAX_N));
    printf("\n");

    // b)
    printf("Memoization: %d\n",knapsackMemoized(MAX_CAPACITY, M1, P1, MAX_N));
    printf("Memoization: %d\n",knapsackMemoized(MAX_CAPACITY, M2, P2, MAX_N));
    printf("\n");

    // c)
    printf("Dynamic Programming: %d\n",knapsackDynamic(MAX_CAPACITY, M1, P1, MAX_N));
    printf("Dynamic Programming: %d\n",knapsackDynamic(MAX_CAPACITY, M2, P2, MAX_N));

}

int main() {
    test();
}
```

This is the output I currently get. The recursive method should be supplying the correct result, but the dynamic programming one currently doesn't output the same. Memoization is not done yet, hence it doesn't output correctly either.

```
Recursion: 170
Recursion: 309

Memoization: 2686680
Memoization: 2686600

Dynamic Programming: 0
Dynamic Programming: 270

Process returned 25 (0x19)   execution time : 0.269 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns  out that the code I used for writing the dynamic programming part was supposed to work with `int m[MAX_N+1][MAX_CAPACITY+1];` instead of int `m[MAX_N][MAX_CAPACITY];`.

Changing that has gotten me to a working code, if not really the code I wanted.